# Elasticsearch latest article query for set of ids

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch gurus,

I have articles in Elasticsearch which have related ids. For a set of ids, I want to get the latest article for each of the ids in one query.

An example of an articles in ES is as follows:

```
"id": "ARTICLE1",
"title": "Some title",
"description": "Some description",
"link": "Some link",
"publishedDate": "2020-05-19T23:49:13.000+0000",
"relatedEntities": [
    {
        "id": "REL1",
        "type": "RELATIONSHIP",
    },
    {
        "id": "REL2",
        "type": "RELATIONSHIP",
    }, etc
}

"id": "ARTICLE2",
"title": "Some title",
"description": "Some description",
"link": "Some link",
"publishedDate": "2020-04-19T23:49:13.000+0000",
"relatedEntities": [
    {
        "id": "REL3",
        "type": "RELATIONSHIP",
    },
    {
        "id": "REL4",
        "type": "RELATIONSHIP",
    }, etc
}
```

Here is the query I have so far:

```
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "relatedEntities.id.keyword": [
                "REL1",
                "REL3",
                etc
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": "0",
    "aggs": {
        "latest_article": {
            "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                    {
                        "publishedDate": {
                            "order": "desc"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "_source": {
                    "includes": [
                        "id", "publishedDate"
                    ]
                },
                "size": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I want a result like this:

```
"REL1": {
   "id": "ARTICLE1",
   "publishedDate": "2020-05-22T09:26:48.000+0000"
   // etc. article fields
},
"REL3": {
   "id": "ARTICLE2",
   "publishedDate": "2020-04-22T09:26:48.000+0000"
   // etc. article fields
}
etc.
```

As articles can have other relationships in `relatedEntities`, I don't want those aggregated/returned.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is your expected out? I'm trying to understand what is the problem with the current behavior...

Comment: Added excepted output. At the moment, I seem to only be getting one result in the aggregation result but I expect two.

Comment: Could you please share your mapping info? That'd be helpful